# Data (type double) mismatch between ArcMap and ArcGIS Server 10.6.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, oracle-spatial, double

When I identify a feature which is having a double value as 0.00001 in ArcMap, it is showing what is expected. I have the layer published as a map service using ArcGIS Server. If I search for the same feature through Query Task of Map Service, I am getting the value as 9.999999999999999E-6. Below are some values where I identified such behavior.

Value in ArcMap : -123.0102,
Value in ArcGIS Server Rest Endpoint : -123.01020000000001

Value in ArcMap : 0.00001,
Value in ArcGIS Server Rest Endpoint : 9.999999999999999E-6

Value in ArcMap : -1.23456789,
Value in ArcGIS Server Rest Endpoint : -1.2345678900000001

**Field Details from ArcMap:** *Number Format*:  Numeric, *Data Type*: Double, *Precision*: 38, *Scale*:                    8

**Products:** ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1, ArcGIS Server 10.6.1, Oracle DB

Comment: You're comparing a formatted string value with an unformatted string value. This is a well-known IT issue with IEEE floating-point values, for which delta comparison within an absolute epsilon is the standard solution.

Comment: Thank you for reply @Vince. I'm sorry but I am not aware of 'delta comparison within an absolute epsilon' that you mentioned. Can you please proved a reference or a link which I can read through to understand that. Also, my main purpose is to fetch the value from ArcGIS Server rest endpoint for further use. what's happening here is that the value itself is getting changed. Like the DB is having value of 0.00001 but the value coming out of rest endpoint is 9.999999999999999E-6, even if I convert that value from exponent, I am not getting exact value as in DB.

Comment: No, the value itself is *not* being changed, just the number of significant digits in the display. In fact, the value offered by AGS is closer to the actual value than your expectation. A comment is *way* too small to delve into number theory, IEEE floating-point representation and ASCII equivalents, but there are scores of pages dedicated to it for the curious.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known limitation in ArcMap and Server when having a field with the double data type.

The reason behind this unaccepted behavior is the conversion of floating-point values to A machine recognizable binary format.

Find an explanation here, [IEEE Floating Point].[1](http://wiki-1-1930356585.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/wiki/index.php/Floating_point)